# number of files and subdirectories of current directory

Tags: unix

I want to count the files and subdirectories of current directory also the . directory from current directory

Output example:

```
$ ./count_files.sh
42
```

Comment: what have you tried? Please read [help] before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use find to print all directories files and subdirectories and files within them. Then pipe to wc to count them all.

```
find . | wc -l
```